# Resources file configurable in multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have one parent project which has WAR and JAR project. Currently the .xml and .properties files are packaged with jar. My requirement is that I want the resources folder of jar project which as .xml and .properties files to be available in WEB-INF folder of the war when the war project is build.

So that I can edit the files when the war is deployed on server.

Comment: Do you really need to put content of this file in WEB-INF directory? What do you want to achieve by that? Have a look at web fragment definition in Servlets 3.x spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to share resources across multiple projects or modules:

1. Cut and paste them.
2. Use Assembly and Dependency plugins
3. Use the maven-remote-resources-plugin

the second approach is described [here](http://blog.sonatype.com/2008/04/how-to-share-resources-across-projects-in-maven/#.VV2Bgfmqqko)

the third approach is described [here](http://blog.sonatype.com/2008/04/how-to-share-resources-across-projects-in-maven/#.VV2Bgfmqqko)